# get array of elements having specific href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need array of elements (inside `story`) having `href` attribute starts with `view.php`.

Here are my tryings, without success:

```js
let arr = $('#story').find(".el[href.startsWith('view.php')]");
//let arr = $('#story').find(".el[attr('href').startsWith('view.php')]");

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='story'>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=323'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'about.php'>ipsum</a>
<a class='el' href = 'index.php'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=525'>ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `a[href^="view.php"]` starts with attribute selector and then get array of `href` values with `map` and `get` methods.

```js
let arr = $('#story a[href^="view.php"]').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('href')
}).get()

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='story'>
  <a class='el' href='view.php?id=323'>lorem</a>
  <a class='el' href='about.php'>ipsum</a>
  <a class='el' href='index.php'>lorem</a>
  <a class='el' href='view.php?id=525'>ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: pls help on this way - `let arr = $('#story').find(".el[href^='view.php']");` I nedd array of  `el's`

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelectorAll('#story > a[href^="view.php"]')`

Comment: result  + some strange text in console, pls try

Comment: Yep, it returns an NodeList object ! You can convert it to array easily with `[...myNodeList]`. Now you should be able to loop over it like a regular array :)

Answer (score 1):

This one prints 2 times hello for this situation.

```js
let arr = [];
$('a[href^="view.php"]').each(function() {
    arr.push(this.getAttribute("href"));
});

console.log(arr[0])
console.log(arr[1])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='story'>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=323'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'about.php'>ipsum</a>
<a class='el' href = 'index.php'>lorem</a>
<a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=525'>ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: and where is the array wanted ?

Comment: Added it for you.

Comment: the first one is missing

Comment: Ofcourse, I log the second one.Added the first one for you:)

Comment: upvoted, but I need array of `el's` not `href's`, pls see my comment on `Nenad Vracar's` post

Comment: I don't understand what you really need then. What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('el')

const views = Array.prototype.filter.call(
  links,
  el =>  el.getAttribute('href').startsWith('view')
);

console.log(views)
```

```html
<div id='story'>
  <a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=323'>First view link</a>
  <a class='el' href = 'about.php'>ipsum</a>
  <a class='el' href = 'index.php'>lorem</a>
  <a class='el' href = 'view.php?id=525'>Second view link</a>
</div>
```